# How to go back to parent directory on back button press?

Tags: android

Below is my code, which checks whether the selected file is a directory or a file. If it is a directory it changes into it. But how do I goes back to parent directory on back button press?

I see somehwere in Stackflow a code which goes `root.parent` when backpress but now I did not found that code.

```
    gridView =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
    position,long id) {


    if(currentFiles[position].isDirectory())
    {
        root = new File("/data/data/com.myexample
 /files/"+FileName(currentFilePath[position])+"/");

        Log.e("Root first",root+ " ");

        currentFiles = root.listFiles();

        inflateListView(currentFiles);
    }


     private void inflateListView(File[] files){


List<Map<String,Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();


for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)

{       
    Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if(files[i].isDirectory())
    {
        listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
    }
    else
    {
        listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.file);
    }

    listItem.put("fileName", files[i].getName());
    listItems.add(listItem);
  }

simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,listItems,R.layout.line,new String[]
{"icon","fileName"},new int[]{R.id.icon,R.id.file_name});
gridView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Comment: Did you try any of the answers? You really should upvote/accept if an answer helped you and comment/downvote if an answer was wrong or not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method that is called on backpressed:

```
    /** {@inheritDoc}. */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.currentDirectory.getParent() != null) {
        // --> browse one folder up...
    } else {
        // --> you are already at the root folder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to detect if the back button is pressed. You have several options:

1) Override [View.onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

2) Override [Activity.onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

3) Override [Activity.onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) (called if no views have handled the key press):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Save your path in a String variable say `dirname` and initialize it to your root directory.

Initialize
`String dirname=<your-root-directory>;`

Slightly change your `onItemClick` as

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    if(currentFiles[position].isDirectory())
    {
        dirname=dirname+FileName(currentFilePath[position])+"/";  //changes here
        root = new File(dirname);

        Log.e("Root first",root+ " ");

        currentFiles = root.listFiles();
        inflateListView(currentFiles);
    }
}
```

For going back to your parent directory on pressing back button, write the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    if(dirname.equals(<your-root-directory>))
    {
         super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
    {
        dirname=dirname.substring(0, dirname.lastIndexOf("/"));
        root = new File(dirname);
        Log.e("Root first",root+ " ");
        currentFiles = root.listFiles();
        inflateListView(currentFiles);
    }
}
```

Any doubts, share here.

Comment: You need to initialize `dirname` to top most directory. Above that directory pressing back will perform default operation. Example, set `String dirname="/data/";` or any other top level directory. Feel free to ask further doubts.