# onBackPressed() back to Activity, not folder

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

I want to access the folder with other folders and files to see them and press the back button to return to the main view.
But when I press the back button, it returns me to the previous folder in the directory I am in. Only if I give it several times back, it returns to main view.
Is there a way to force it back to main view by pressing the Back button only once or maybe some way to create a floating button to create a new Intent once ACTION_GET_CONTENT is used?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....
        projectList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Just to see existing folders
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                        .setType("file/*");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                startActivityForResult(i, CODE_SEE_FOLDER);
            }
        });
    }
...

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_SEE_FOLDER);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CODE_SEE_FOLDER && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your projects..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            recreate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355937/how-to-go-back-to-parent-directory-on-back-button-press

Comment: @Usama Altaf Thanks for your answer. I have tried these options, but they do not work for me since I do not have any ListView and I am using ACTION_GET_CONTENT ONLY TO SEE THE CONTENT. I also overrided the method onBackPressed() but still does not working..

Comment: you can call the action get content again in the onBackPressed method

Comment: @UsamaAltaf But I don't need to call ACTION_GET_CONTENT again when pressing Back button, I want just go back to Main View

Comment: what is the mainView of your App

Comment: @Usama Altaf Exactly. From main view I call Intent.ACTION_GET_GONTENT - open the folder. And to return from there, I press the Back button and it does not come back to main view.

Comment: You should never call this: `super.onBackPressed()` if you want to start a new intent, just return true. Call that super only when you want to back.

Comment: Thank you. Still does not working..